# Why doesn't Install4J update i4jruntime.jar?

Tags: install4j

I'm upgrading from Install4J version 4 to version 6. After making the appropriate changes in my code, I ran the newly-built upgrader to update the original software installation, and found that my software launcher is updated but the i4jruntime.jar file is not updated. The result is that my application won't run because of "Error: Could not find or load main class com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher"

When I manually copy i4jruntime.jar (version 6) over i4jruntime.jar (version 4) in the .install4j folder, then my application launches just fine.

I read the [help docs](http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/index.html) on Generated Installers > Updates, but it seems like this is more about updating your software, not updating Install4J itself.

How can I get Install4J to update the i4jruntime.jar file itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The runtime will be upgraded unless you have set the installer type to "Add-on installer" on the "Installer->Update options" step or if you have deselected the "Install runtime" property on the "Install files" action.

Comment: My "Install files" action does have "Install runtime" checked, and it is an add-on installer. So is it true to say that the only way I can update i4jruntime is to change the installer type from add-on installer to a regular installer? If I want to keep this installer as an add-on installer, is my final option to add the i4jruntime jar to the distribution tree?

Comment: The add-on installer is not suitable for upgrades, it's just for add-ons. It cannot even update the version number. Adding i4jruntime.jar to the distribution tree will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! The documentation (http://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/doc/index.html#install4j.steps.installer.updateOptions) says the add-on installer is "useful to distribute patches and enhancements" and I interpreted that as "suitable for upgrades".